# Is there a phrase for people who love getting physically tired?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests

Is there a phrase for people who love getting physically tired?

I tried to search it on the web but couldn't find a proper term for this particular personality type.

Comment: I think it might be the physically active part *before* becoming tired that they enjoy, rather than *being* tired. An exercise addict loves to exercise, and becoming tired afterwards is very likely (or they’d exercise more, until they were tired).

Comment: That oughtta be sorta *fatigu(e)ophile*.

Comment: *Gym junkie*? :)

Comment: Actually, it's "*Kopophilia*, Love of fatigue. Is this just an excuse to sleep more?" *Philes and phobias* https://ohmyword.xyz/words/philes-and-phobias/  --  ELU may want you to search a bit harder, or the Q may get closed.

Comment: better check kopophilia - fatigue due to a particular errr ... exercise! (medical dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

in a way "workaholic" might be an accurate term.
Maybe you could give a little more information?
Do you mean the effort which get's the people tired, or just the feeling of being exhausted, which they like?

Comment: Workaholics are *ergophiles*.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as *adrenaline junkie* we have *fitness junkie* or *exercise junkie*. Neither appears to be in male dictionaries but *fitness junkie* at least has been used for years [including in newspapers](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/could-you-be-a-fitness-junkie-1524045.html). The *exercise-* variant seems a better fit in your case though.

Is worth noting that *junkie* as *[with modifier] A person with a compulsive habit or obsessive dependency on something.* [(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/junkie) is established.